# Plotly in R Set Individual Stacked Bar Width

Tags: r, plotly, visualization, r-plotly, plotly.js

From Plotly tutorial I know  how to set individual bar width like this:

```
library(plotly)

x= c(1, 2, 3, 5.5, 10)
y= c(10, 8, 6, 4, 2)
width = c(0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 3.5, 4)
data <- data.frame(x, y, width)

p <- plot_ly(data) %>%
  add_bars(
    x= ~x,
    y= ~y,
    width = ~width
  )
```

And it will produce nice various width:

[image]

However, when I try to replicate this with stacked bar graphs, it doesn't work:

```
x = c(1, 2, 3, 5.5, 10,1, 2, 3, 5.5, 10)
y = c(10, 8, 6, 4, 2,0,2,4,6,8)
width = c(0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 3.5, 4,0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 3.5, 4)
group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B")
data <- data.frame(x, y, width, group)

p <- data %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  plot_ly(
    x= ~x,
    y= ~y,
    width = ~width,
    color = ~group,
    colors = 'Reds',
    type = "bar"
  ) %>%
  layout(barmode = 'stack')
```

It gives the error:

```
> print(p)
Error in validateCssUnit(sizeInfo$width) : 
  CSS units must be a single-element numeric or character vector
In addition: Warning message:
In is.na(x) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'language'
```

Of course comment out "width = ~width" then my code works perfectly. But I really need to adjust bar width for my graph. Is there anyone knowing the solution to this?

Comment: Looks like you need to add another trace (check official docs about stacked bar [first](https://plot.ly/r/bar-charts/#stacked-bar-chart)). So, your plot should be consist on two traces. If you want to change width, you need to specify width parameter on first trace and on second trace. Do not forget, those width should be the same! Hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ggplotly` as an alternative. You could try this:

```
ggplotly(ggplot(data = data, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = group, width = width)) + geom_col() + theme_bw())
```